# Matter and antimatter differences?

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

I've heard (and after googling for a while, found) that the only difference between matter and anti-matter is simply charge. This bothers me when it comes to the neutron. Matter and anti-matter annihilate when they come together, so in the case of the neutron, what we'd have is just two neutrons coming together; that shouldn't result in anything like a positron and electron- the neutrons are exactly the same!

I can think of two solutions to my doubt. 
1) There are other 'subtler' (not so commonly mentioned) differences between matter and anti-matter that would differentiate between a neutron and anti-neutron. 
2) Maybe the reason the neutron and anti-neutron annihilate is that the quarks they are made from change (instead of having two down and one up quark, the anti-neutron would have two anti-down and one anti-up quark?). This seems like the most logical explanation to me, although it's kind of strange; the individual quarks would 'do the annihilation', not the neutron itself. Is this what's going on?

Sorry for my ignorance- I know almost nothing about the subject of anti-matter (or particle physics, or even barely any QM unfortunately).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> the only difference between matter and anti-matter is simply charge

Nope. All "quantum numbers" reverse for them. In particular, for the example you consider, there's [Baryon number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number), which is different for baryons and anti-baryons, and in particular, for a neutron and its anti-particle, an [antineutron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antineutron). It is in fact possible to differentiate between the two, in spite of the fact that both of them have identical mass and zero charge. This is by studying what they decay into - their decay products are different. While a neutron decays into a proton, electron and an anti-nuetrino (you probably know that the process is called [beta decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay)), the decay modes of an antineutron would have antiproton, positron and neutrino as the daughter species. The two cases CAN be experimentally distinguished.

So, your possible solution 1 for the doubt is correct:

> There are other 'subtler' (not so commonly mentioned) differences between matter and anti-matter that would differentiate between a neutron and anti-neutron.

Actually, if you take into account the quark content for the neutron and anti-neutron, even explanation no. 2 is correct. The two explanations aren't independent, see the baryon number definition (in terms of quark content) in the first link of the answer.